# spring mvc ajax @ModelAttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, spring

In my Spring MVC application I have a data table, and I am using ajax and json to populate the data with pagination sorting etc. by the help of `jquery.dataTables.js`. like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#accordion").hide();

        $("#productList").dataTable({
            "bProcessing" : true,
            "iDisplayLength" : 10,
            "iDisplayStart" : 0,
             -------------
             --------------

            "sAjaxSource" :  ....'/product/productList',
            "aoColumns" : [ {
                "mData" : "year"
            }, {
                "mData" : "catg"
            }, {
                "mData" : "name"
```

Where on table I am displaying 4 columns.
Now On click on each row I want to show the details of selected record, around 50 fields.

I can achieve by `jquery`, the time data table loading I can have get all the properties value to `json` and can set each id of 50 fields on click of each record.

```
var table = $('#productList').DataTable();

$('#productList tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {

    $("#accordion").show();

    var data = table.row(this).data();

    $('#type').val(data.type);
    $('#expdate').val(data.expDate);
    $('#place').val(data.place);
    $('#status').val(data.status);
```

But I want to use `@ModelAttribute` or `model` on click of a record It will do a ajax call set on ModelAttribute.so the deatils of record section will be inside form and each field have spring form path.

Is it possible?.please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) approach, because here they use hidden data.

All you need is replace 
`row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();` with something like that: `row.child( format(fetchDataFromServer(row.data().id)) ).show();`

DataTable changed their API, so it have to be changed according to old API doc or you can switch to use new version of library.

**UPD:** Found a [link](https://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html) to legacy API example. Here you'll need to modify `fnFormatDetails` function invocation and pass data from server.